# write on a csv column and change header

Tags: python, csv

i'm trying to use python to make a script that change a csv, i have to ask for an input that will be the same for all the lines and also have to change an header name but not all the values listed, here is the script

```
import csv
location= input("File Path: ")
with open(location) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    with open('fixed.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_file:
        
        fieldnames = "value", "type", "description"
        writer=csv.writer(new_file)

        csv_writer =csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter= '|', extrasaction='ignore')
        csv_writer.writeheader()

        for line in csv_reader:
            line = {k: v.replace("sha1", "hash") for k, v in line.items()}
            
   
            if not any("url" in value for value in line.values()):
                csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Here is the code, i have to change "value" header to a new word, and list under "description" the same thing that is asked to the user

sample of csv

```
value|type|description
35|new|
46|new|
54|new|
```

Comment: Why don't you use `pandas`?

Comment: I'm new to python and don't know how to use it

Comment: Be more specific about the CSV file and show us the input(it could be at least a part of CSV) and the desired output. We need more information to help you.

Comment: i updated the post with a sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the csv writer you need to declare the column names like so.

```
fieldnames = "new_column_name", "type", "description"
```

If you are Using python 3.7+
replace this line

```
line = {k: v.replace("sha1", "hash") for k, v in line.items()}
```

with

```
line = {"new_column_name" if k == 'value' else k:v.replace("sha1", "hash") for k,v in line.items()}
```

Otherwise, the following will work for any version. place this code after initializing the line variable

```
line = {'new_columne_name' : line['value'], 'type': line['type'], 'description' : line['description']}
```

if you want to change the value of the description at a certain line simply use this

```
line['description'] = new_value
```

Comment: it doesn't work, value is not changing to the new name,the description change works, i'm using python 3.6

Comment: you need to also change the fieldnames to the new column names, see the edit at the beginning of the answer

Comment: ok now it worked, thanks